# asp.net literal text values contained in ajax accordion migrating south for the winter

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So I've got an ajax accordion condensing my filter contents like so:

```
<asp:Accordion ID="accSchools" runat="server">
    <Panes>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="apnSchViaDDL" runat="server">
            <Header><h2 class="opt">Select Schools (p1)</h2></Header>
            <Content>
                Pane 1 Content
                <table><tr>
                <asp:Literal ID="litDdlSchs" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </tr></table>
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>

        <asp:AccordionPane ID="apnSchViaChk" runat="server">
            <Header><h2 class="opt">Select Schools by School (p2)</h2></Header>
            <Content>
                Pane 2 Content
                <table style="width:99%; text-align:right;">
                    <asp:Literal ID="litSchsChks" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </table>
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>

        <asp:AccordionPane ID="apnSchViaGrnt" runat="server">
            <Header><h2 class="opt">Select Schools by Grant (p3)</h2></Header>
            <Content>
                Pane 3 Content
                <table style="width:99%; text-align:right;">
                    <asp:Literal ID="litSchsGrnt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </table>
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>

        <asp:AccordionPane ID="apnSchDummyPane" runat="server">
            <Header><h2 class="opt">Dummy Pane (p4)</h2></Header>
            <Content>
                Pane 4 Content
                <asp:Literal ID="litSafetyNet" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
</asp:Accordion>
```

The problem is, on postback, the literals all shift their text value down by one. litDdlSchs.Text reverts to "", litSchChks.Text is now what litDdlSchs.Text was, etc... with litSafetyNet falling off a cliff into the bit bucket.

Currently I have SafetyNet catching the lit that would fall off otherwise, and am manually pulling them back up. But this feels..... clunky.
Anyone have any idea what would be causing my literal text values to migrate south for the winter?

EDIT: Okay so, SafetyNet actually didn't work, I merely thought of it as I was typing this and didn't wanna seem dumb for not having tried it.
Reloading all of my literals every page load DOES fix it, but... part of why I did it the way I did was so I wouldn't have to reload the literals every time- two of them are nearly 30k characters with very minor formatting applied to the html they're producing (so I could verify I wasn't leaving off some close tag).

EDIT 2: The fix *does* work, I'm just bad at implementing things in a panic apparently (to be fair it'd have worked if I had finished implementing SchGrnts's setter). Fixed SafetyNet, and it's working. Also have it set so if the net is actually empty, it'll not pull up, so if I ever accidentally fix this, nothing breaks.

EDIT 3:
**The question still remains**: Anyone have any idea what would be causing my literal text values to migrate south for the winter?

Comment: Er right, predecessor shortcutted ajax: to asp:. Afraid to change it due to likely explosions.

Comment: I never answered my own question:
Anyone have any idea what would be causing my literal text values to migrate south for the winter?
The edit updates were related to my workaround, not the underlying problem- which is the entire reason I bothered posting this here, as my workaround is honestly pretty clean, even if a bit janky.