# Asp.net Button Firing Other Button's Event

Tags: asp.net

I have a set of options on an ASP.net page where the user may open up one of two lightboxes - either the "Add" lightbox or the "Edit" lightbox.

Each one has a small form for the user to fill out, and then they can hit a button at the bottom of the lightbox to hit submit.

I have the buttons set up within the lightboxes like so:

```
<asp:Button Id="btnSubmitAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitAdd_Click" />
```

... then later in the other lightbox...

```
<asp:Button Id="btnSubmitEdit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitEdit_Click" />
```

When i click the "Add" lightbox's submit button, everything behaves just fine.

When i click the "Edit" lightbox's submit button however, it fires "btnSubmitAdd_Click" instead of its own "...Edit_Click" event!

I have checked and re-checked all of the names and events and everything is set up correctly.  Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you compared the rendered HTML result to check differences there?  Your ASP.NET markup looks fine; have you checked if `btnSubmitEdit.OnClick` is wired up differently in the code-behind?

Comment: This reminds me of [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417302/asp-net-literal-text-values-contained-in-ajax-accordion-migrating-south-for-the) I had a while back ...  

Try adding another button after Edit, and see if clicking it fires the Edit event. Does not need a value for its OnClick.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie - The events are wired up correctly, yes.  I notice now that the rendered HTML shows " type="submit" " where I would expect to see something more like " type="button" ".  I'm investigating what that difference means now...

Comment: @EthanTheBrave `button`s are just a button ui that has no innate event binding. `submit`s are button uis that have the innate binding of (attempting) submitting the form. On their submitting the form, they map their `name` attribute to their `value` attribute in the form data sent to the server. Friendly reminder that ASP.NET is very magical and not everything maps exactly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @MikeGuthrie for leading me down the correct path!

The issue seems to be with asp.net defaulting buttons to type "submit" which submits the entire form, and apparently that means it simply hit the first button's event before the second.

I added have modified the buttons like so and things are working now:

```
<asp:Button Id="btnSubmitAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitAdd_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>

<asp:Button Id="btnSubmitEdit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitEdit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

Comment: Not gonna lie, the reason that that fixed it alludes me. By default, submitting with a  `submit` input in HTML submits the entire form, yes, but only the `name:value` of the submit button pressed is kept (out of all submit buttons). So the server should have still been able to figure out which event actually needed to fire. EDIT: Looking at the difference, turning off USB does the submit via js, which attaches the event target. Just submitting doesn't.

Comment: @abluejelly - Perhaps someone with a better understanding than I can explain.  All I know is what I've read (which I put in my answer) and that it now works.  It could just be broken in a new, much more deceptive way!  I have a tendency to break things in interesting ways.

Comment: It seems to me to be caused by the ASP OnClick events firing based on the `__EVENTTARGET` passed up with the data. The base submit doesn't set it to something other than `''`, so you have to turn off the UseSubmitBehavior attribute for asp to use the js submit which will attach a meaningful value. As for why ASP chooses to not just use the natural `name:value` 'feature' of submit buttons when it's available... That's the real question.